# How to get permissions for data models in the azure analysis service servers for a particular user using REST api calls

Tags: azure, data-analysis, azure-analysis-services, azure-rbac

I am trying to get permissions for data model created inside a azure analysis services servers. I am able to get the permissions for particular servers using `Azure rest APIs` (eg. `GET` of `https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.AnalysisServices/operations?api-version=2016-05-16`), but I am not able to find the REST APIs to get the permissions assigned to data model inside a server.

Can anyone help me how to get permissions for a particular table or a column inside the model?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK  there is none . The rest API offering for AAS is very [limited .](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/analysisservices/)